# Is this too much for one developer?

Tags: career-development, careers, job-description

**Background**: my company makes IoT devices. All the data generated by the IoT devices gets sent to the cloud. I would like one developer to be responsible for everything after the data leaves the device. More specifically, they'd be responsible for maintaining/improving the *frontend* and *backend* (see below descriptions) while, at the same time, develop all future features.

**Question(s)**: Is this too much to ask for a single developer? If so, how many devs should I realistically have? (I realize this is a high-level description and that you may have questions...but your initial reaction or any feedback would be welcome.)

**Frontend**: the software is multi-tenant and features realtime updates to the frontends. The frontends (web and mobile) are all somewhat similar with roughly a dozen screens for each app and includes authentication, role-based access control, data computations, graphing, user management, and much more. The admin frontend is different. It contains about 15 screens and includes features that allows our company to manage tenants and users, provision and manage devices, deploy software to our IoT devices, and monitor the health of our device fleet via a dashboard. The web frontends have been created with React, the mobile apps have been created with Flutter.

**Backend**: we use 20 AWS services. Data ingestion starts with AWS’s IoT service. IoT rules forward the data to the appropriate Lambda for the data to be checked/cleaned and then stored in RDS. Currently, we have 45 Lambdas, 15 API endpoints and 30 tables in the database with about 750k rows of data. We also employ various AWS services to communicate in realtime with the frontend (SNS, Pinpoint, and IoT). We also use Google for push notifications, looking up GPS coordinates and displaying maps on the frontends.

Deployment is automated via AWS Code Deploy services to our three environments (dev, staging, and prod). Here is a simplified diagram of our architecture.

[image: Architecture]

**Data**: Lastly, it’s worth mentioning that there is quite a heavy data component to this job. Data will constantly need to be imported (via various Excel files), as well as exported and translated via Google’s Translate API into various language packs. Each language pack contains about 24k rows of data.  Database administration is also expected (e.g. performance analysis, adding indexes, query optimization, etc.).

Comment: I do not think there is any way this question can be answered.  From a brief read it is possible a MVP could be cobbled together with open source tools and a bit of scripting between them by one person.  That is not the same as saying a saleable product could be.  You can have quick, cheap, good.  Pick two.

Comment: You need to get an estimate of the actual workload on a daily basis.  Be very conservative.

Comment: Well, that depends on a lot of factors, especially what developer you get. Senior? Junior? Fresh out of College? Is the new colleague up to speed with all used technology, or does he need training? I would onboard someone, and then look how the workload is for that colleague. Can some part of the job be automated? If the colleague gets overwhelmed, I'd hire a second one (Given you have the budget. If not, you need to cut corners).

Comment: ...it also depends on the time. If the sole developer has to spend all their time fixing bugs in production, they won't have any time to develop new features. Maybe that's ok? Or maybe it's super-reliable and they'll have lots of time to do that. Or maybe the sales team don't need new features until Q4 2026. It all really depends.

Comment: This is not a question about the workplace. This is a question about software development.

Comment: You should not expose your company's UMLs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this too much to ask for a single developer?

Without thinking about the technical implementation at all: no, it's not too much. Any developer with a solid education should be able to build that.

However, that probably was not your *actual* question. One developer *can* build it, but are you happy if it takes 15 years? Or 10? Or 7? What if that person quits after 5 years, which would be a quite solid block of time and no job hopper. If you have only one person, that person has no feedback mechanism. Their work might be good. Or not. Are you happy if it's apile of unmaintainable scriptures that run based on faith and hope rather than solid principles a team had to adhere to to work properly?

So to your actual question, **do you need more than one developer**?

## Yes

For so many different reasons, but none of those that you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...and thanks to all the commenters above for chiming in.